# jquery append checked to item

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add checked to this object

```
  ('[name="Medi"]').append('Checked');
```

results in

```
 [<input name=​"Medi" id=​"G" onclick type=​"checkbox">​Checked​</input>​]
```

I want

```
[<input name=​"Medi" id=​"G" onclick type=​"checkbox" checked>​</input>​]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need change the `checked` property of your `<input>`, so use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
$('[name="Medi"]').prop('checked', true);
```

`G` may well be a placeholder for the purpose of this question, but it would be much more efficient for you to select the `id` of that element:

```
$('#G').prop('checked', true);
```